# how to use gii generator with modules in yii framework?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components, gii, form-generator

i am using the gii generator to create a module.

the issue is when i try to create a form or some model for that module... 
i can't tell it to generate those files in that module... it only does it in the main application folders.

any ideas?

thanks.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a model for a specific module in yii you can give input to the **model path** text field like '**application.modules..models**'.

Comment: where is this from? is there an example?

Comment: I too had faced the same problem and referring some post helped me which I dont remember. Please try this link http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/9724-gii-crud-creation-for-model-in-module/